# MIPS programming separate words in string and store values to their own registers

Tags: assembly, mips

I need to take in a string say:

```
hello world
```

and store each word into its own register say:

```
$s0 and $s1
```

So i can later manipulate what is in those registers. I know when accepting a value from the user the $a1 register contains an array of pointers to the first character of each word, I am getting stuck on how to get to the values in the registers and access them.

Thanks!

Update

As pointed out i cannot just add the values to a register so i need to get the first character of each word and iterate over each character to manipulate them. I wrote this code to get the first character of the string but if I change 0($s0) to 1($s1) i get an out of bounds error

```
here is some code i have written to get the first character. 

if i change 0($s0) to 1($s0)
```

i get an out of bounds error so i cant get the next character that way

```
la $a0, prompt    #print title
li $v0, 4
syscall

li $v0, 8
la $a0, input       #store value
lw $a1, inputSize   #store size
move $s0, $a0       #store string into character for safe keeping
syscall

la $a0, output      #output string
li $v0, 4
syscall

lw $a0, 1($s0)
li $v0, 11          #print string
syscall
```

Comment: What do you mean by "each word into own register"? MIPS has 32b (=4B) registers, so you can store at most 4 ASCII characters into them, string "hello" has 5 bytes in memory. That's why code manipulating with strings usually does use pointer to first character of string into register, not the string itself. Then by that pointer you can manipulate with single letters, as needed.  ... and to load byte value from address you can use `lb` (load byte) instruction. `sb` is "store byte".

Comment: ok so i think i have been thinking about this wrong. I was thinking about this like a higher level language where i could separate the words and store them in variables (in this case registers) then manipulate them. It doesnt appear thats a possibility. In that case how would i go about getting the first char of each word then?

Comment: I wrote a comment here but it wont let me put in code so ill add it to the top

Comment: your new problem is, because you didn't pay attention to the data size you are working with. I was mentioning ASCII and **BYTES**. Yet you are doing `lw` = load **word**, so you are effectively loading 4 letters at the same time, as the ASCII is usually encoded 1 byte = 1 ASCII code (even when basic ASCII fits only 7 bits). The `0($s0)` memory address works for `lw` because your `input` buffer starts at word-aligned address, but `1($s0)` (not $s1 as you wrote in text) means memory address `s0 + 1`, which is not word aligned = unaligned word access = crash. `lb` (load **byte**) would work.

Comment: If you don't want to struggle on every other line of assembly, get back to what is *bit*, *byte*, *word* (on MIPS it is 32 bit value, on different platforms it may be defined differently, for example `word` in x86 world is 16 bit), and what does that mean for memory addressing, and what is the range of values which fits into 8/16/32/64 bits... Keep refreshing this knowledge until you can tell on midnight that 16 bit signed integer value has range -32768 to + 32767 and occupies 2 bytes in memory (yep, I didn't need to check any docs for this one, just wrote it from head).

Comment: @Midi_: you could store a *pointer* to the start of a word.  You could replace the spaces with a `0` byte so each word is an implicit-length string (like you could pass to `puts` or `printf`).